# A/B testing support for React pages

Tags: firebase, multivariate-testing, firebase-ab-testing

I am trying to use Firebase A/B Testing for website variants. I have a doubt that does Firebase A/B Testing support for React.JS page as well? A/B Testing solutions can work for initial page load, but not when React like pages doesn't get refreshed. React JS page makes every user interaction to prompt for each UI elements refresh, which causes to erase any modifications done by A/B testing solution.

But, Some of A/B testing vendors such as Optimizely and Adobe are supporting A/B Testing support for React.JS page as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*firebaser here*

Firebase A/B Testing is available for Android and iOS. It is not available for web apps, so won't work in a ReactJS web app.

Comment: Is it not supported for Web? I think, it is supported for iOS, Android and Web but not supported for React.JS single page app. Firebase A/B Testing is on top Cloud messaging, RemoteConfig. I guess, Cloud messaging supported for Web, hence A/B Testing is also supported for Web.

Comment: As said: Firebase A/B Testing is not supported in web apps, including ReactJS.